# associating HP MSA2000 G3 to a virtual machine on windows server 2012 DC

Tags: virtualization, storage-area-network, debian-squeeze, hyper-v-server-2012

Basically i wanted to have a Debian Squeeze associated to the SAN HP MSA200 G3 but due to lack of support i have now planned to deploy Windows Server 2012 Data-center on 2xHP Proliant DL380p G7 servers and add the role of Hyper V and create the virtual machine of Debian Squeeze.

Now, i would require assistance for the as i would be able to associate the SAN which is connected over fiber channel and associate LUN of 3TB on Raid5 to the Servers but can anybody let me know how to associate the same LUN to the virtual machine such that the LUN is attached to the Debain Squeeze...?

Sorry if my question seemed a bit not well documented but i tried to clearly portray the entire Scenario..be waiting for your response.

Thank you.

---

@Rex the thing is i tried a lot of ways which are listed as follows :

1) I tried adding the Physical hard drive by selecting the drive by the Physical drive option in the console of the virtual hard drive but the option itself is grayed out and doesn't allow me to select now gives me a drop down menu to choose the number of drive that i would want to add.

2) I have tried assigning SAN to the virtual machine created by associting the SAN through Virtual SAN manager in Hyper-V, it gives out a error message stating the fiber channel SAN isn't supported and the virtual machine doesnt start on both the DB Servers during the time of boot.

3) I have then went ahead and created a New virtual disk of 2.6Tb on the drive over SAN location which makes the SAN partition detectable on both the serves as i associated them as a virtual hard drive but issue occurring is the changes made through the first server aint being reflected on the drive while i am trying to access it through the second DB server.(Even tried restarting it)

**error : The /dev/sdb have a bad magic number and doesnt have a valid partition table.**

4) I tried creating and adding the virtual hard drive created on SAN drive Via ISCSI which causes the second DB server to give an error the the ISCSI drive isnt accessable.

can anybody suggest any other way to do it..?

Comment: Are you using fiber or iSCSI? Your previous question (http://serverfault.com/questions/579280/how-to-configure-hp-msa20000-g3-on-a-hp-proliant-dl380p-g7-server-on-debian-sque) mentioned fiber channel, here you are talking about iSCSI.. which is it?

Comment: my fault its fiber channel....not ISCSI....rectified it

Answer (score 0):

Your best results will probably come from using the virtual Fibre Channel feature in Hyper-V.  If your HBA is recent and its firmware is fully up to date, and if the switches support NPIV and their firmware is up to date, you can give the VM itself a presence on your FC fabric, with its own World Wide Names.

In order to light this up in the VM itself, you either need a supported version of Linux or you need to install the Linux Integration Services yourself.  I think (from memory) that Debian isn't a supported version, so you're on your own.

You can find what you need to install at this link:

http://www.bing.com/search?q=Linux+Integration+Services+Version+3.5+for+Hyper-V&src=IE-TopResult&FORM=IE11TR&conversationid=

Answer (score 0):

If this is a standalone host, you can also look at using the Disk Pass-Through features in Hyper-V.

I'm curious as to why you want to do it this way vs just created the VHDX files and attaching them directly with Hyper-V. With Hyper-V 2012, you are not limited to 2TB in the new VHDX formats anymore.